# Server Tomcat v8.5 Server at localhost failed to start caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I've tried many options related to this error. It's been almost 4 days and I can't figure out why this is still showing.

I reinstalled tomcat, eclipse and my whole OS .

[Error eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xhq40.png)

Hope somebody has a quick fix.

Comment: Post error messages as text, not images.

Comment: I'm glad your issue is resolved. Since you're a new StackOverflow member, always do some research on the issues before posting to StackOverflow. It's highly likely your problems are already answered.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of some missing jars. Make sure that these jars exist in your classpath.

1. bootstrap.jar
2. tomcat-juli.jar

For adding these jars,

- Open the Server tab
- Double click on the Tomcat6 entry.
- Then click on the 'Open launch configuration'
- select the Classpath and "Add external jar"

Comment: Alternatively one can use _"Restore Default Entries"_ in the _"Classpath"_ tab: the default entries will not appear immediately, but after the _"Edit Configuration"_ window is opened a second time.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz Thank you for that comment. But many times I observed that Restored Default not working event after the window is reopened.  Not sure the cause of that. But I think we should try "Restore Default" in the first place.

Comment: Sep 13, 2021 12:49:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@49048cf5]

Comment: @DevNocz Check your application whether you have properly configured your servlets

Comment: @Sam Thanks for your help. It worked after deleting my .m2 repository content and rebuilding the project.  Piotr also helped a lot, "Restore Default Entries" in the "Classpath" tab made it easier.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42206853/a-child-container-failed-during-start-java-util-concurrent-executionexception-o