# Tomcat can't open because of maven in several situations

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

These two days,I experience some issues with the maven(I am new to it),all result in the failure to open the tomcat.Here are a few situations:

---

1.After import maven project downloaded from github;

---

2.After changing the dynamic project to maven project;

---

3.After adding some dependencies to the pom.xml;

---

4.After changing databases linked to the maven project;

---

And there may be other situations which makes the tomcat opening problem.Is there any similar situations or any solutions?It's really disappointed that suddenly you can't open the tomcat,maybe just did a few things.If possible I wish there are some explanation.Thank you.
And all the log are:

```
A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/WechatDemo]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/WechatDemo]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileUploadException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:66)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:328)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:778)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:299)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5114)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1285)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
    ... 19 more

七月 10, 2017 8:09:40 下午 org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
严重: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:655)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more

七月 10, 2017 8:09:40 下午 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
严重: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:655)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 11 more
```

The command output is(after tying mvn dependency:tree in my cmd with the project root dictionary):

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building WechatDemo 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ WechatDemo ---
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-sink-api/1.0-
alpha-10/doxia-sink-api-1.0-alpha-10.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-sink-api/1.0-a
lpha-10/doxia-sink-api-1.0-alpha-10.pom (2 KB at 0.5 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia/1.0-alpha-10/
doxia-1.0-alpha-10.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia/1.0-alpha-10/d
oxia-1.0-alpha-10.pom (9 KB at 10.8 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting
-api/3.0/maven-reporting-api-3.0.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-
api/3.0/maven-reporting-api-3.0.pom (3 KB at 4.3 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-sink-api/1.0/
doxia-sink-api-1.0.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-sink-api/1.0/d
oxia-sink-api-1.0.pom (2 KB at 2.9 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia/1.0/doxia-1.0
.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia/1.0/doxia-1.0.
pom (10 KB at 14.7 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-parent/10/maven-par
ent-10.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-parent/10/maven-pare
nt-10.pom (31 KB at 27.9 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting
-impl/2.0.5/maven-reporting-impl-2.0.5.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-
impl/2.0.5/maven-reporting-impl-2.0.5.pom (5 KB at 8.6 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-core/1.0/doxi
a-core-1.0.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-core/1.0/doxia
-core-1.0.pom (3 KB at 0.0 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.7/ple
xus-utils-1.5.7.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.7/plex
us-utils-1.5.7.pom (8 KB at 1.8 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-site-renderer
/1.0/doxia-site-renderer-1.0.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-site-renderer/
1.0/doxia-site-renderer-1.0.pom (5 KB at 6.4 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-sitetools/1.0
/doxia-sitetools-1.0.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-sitetools/1.0/
doxia-sitetools-1.0.pom (10 KB at 10.9 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-i18n/1.0-beta-7
/plexus-i18n-1.0-beta-7.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-i18n/1.0-beta-7/
plexus-i18n-1.0-beta-7.pom (2 KB at 2.2 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-components/1.1.
12/plexus-components-1.1.12.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-components/1.1.1
2/plexus-components-1.1.12.pom (3 KB at 5.9 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-velocity/1.1.7/
plexus-velocity-1.1.7.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-velocity/1.1.7/p
lexus-velocity-1.1.7.pom (2 KB at 4.2 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-container-defau
lt/1.0-alpha-20/plexus-container-default-1.0-alpha-20.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-container-defaul
t/1.0-alpha-20/plexus-container-default-1.0-alpha-20.pom (3 KB at 6.2 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-containers/1.0-
alpha-20/plexus-containers-1.0-alpha-20.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-containers/1.0-a
lpha-20/plexus-containers-1.0-alpha-20.pom (2 KB at 3.1 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.3/plexu
s-utils-1.3.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.3/plexus
-utils-1.3.pom (2 KB at 2.2 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-classworlds/1.2
-alpha-7/plexus-classworlds-1.2-alpha-7.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-classworlds/1.2-
alpha-7/plexus-classworlds-1.2-alpha-7.pom (3 KB at 4.9 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus/1.0.9/plexus-1.
0.9.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus/1.0.9/plexus-1.0
.9.pom (8 KB at 13.4 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/velocity/velocity/1.5/velocity-
1.5.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/velocity/velocity/1.5/velocity-1
.5.pom (8 KB at 13.6 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/oro/oro/2.0.8/oro-2.0.8.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/oro/oro/2.0.8/oro-2.0.8.pom (140 B at 0.3 K
B/sec)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-decoration-mo
del/1.0/doxia-decoration-model-1.0.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-decoration-mod
el/1.0/doxia-decoration-model-1.0.pom (4 KB at 6.4 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-module-apt/1.
0/doxia-module-apt-1.0.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-module-apt/1.0
/doxia-module-apt-1.0.pom (3 KB at 4.5 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-modules/1.0/d
oxia-modules-1.0.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-modules/1.0/do
xia-modules-1.0.pom (3 KB at 4.8 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-module-fml/1.
0/doxia-module-fml-1.0.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-module-fml/1.0
/doxia-module-fml-1.0.pom (3 KB at 5.4 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-module-xdoc/1
.0/doxia-module-xdoc-1.0.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-module-xdoc/1.
0/doxia-module-xdoc-1.0.pom (3 KB at 4.6 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-module-xhtml/
1.0/doxia-module-xhtml-1.0.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-module-xhtml/1
.0/doxia-module-xhtml-1.0.pom (2 KB at 3.4 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-doxia-tools/
1.0.2/maven-doxia-tools-1.0.2.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-doxia-tools/1
.0.2/maven-doxia-tools-1.0.2.pom (6 KB at 11.0 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-compo
nents/11/maven-shared-components-11.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-compon
ents/11/maven-shared-components-11.pom (9 KB at 14.1 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-io/commons-io/1.4/commons-io-1.4.p
om
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-io/commons-io/1.4/commons-io-1.4.po
m (13 KB at 18.6 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-validator/commons-validator/1.2.0/
commons-validator-1.2.0.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-validator/commons-validator/1.2.0/c
ommons-validator-1.2.0.pom (9 KB at 15.0 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-digester/commons-digester/1.6/comm
ons-digester-1.6.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-digester/commons-digester/1.6/commo
ns-digester-1.6.pom (974 B at 2.2 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.6/co
mmons-beanutils-1.6.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.6/com
mons-beanutils-1.6.pom (3 KB at 5.0 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.0/common
s-logging-1.0.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.0/commons
-logging-1.0.pom (163 B at 0.4 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-collections/commons-collections/2.
0/commons-collections-2.0.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-collections/commons-collections/2.0
/commons-collections-2.0.pom (171 B at 0.4 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-collections/commons-collections/2.
1/commons-collections-2.1.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-collections/commons-collections/2.1
/commons-collections-2.1.pom (4 KB at 7.2 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/xml-apis/xml-apis/2.0.2/xml-apis-2.0.2.pom

Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/xml-apis/xml-apis/2.0.2/xml-apis-2.0.2.pom
(346 B at 0.7 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-archiver/2.3/pl
exus-archiver-2.3.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-archiver/2.3/ple
xus-archiver-2.3.pom (4 KB at 7.2 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-components/1.3/
plexus-components-1.3.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-components/1.3/p
lexus-components-1.3.pom (3 KB at 7.1 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus/3.3/plexus-3.3.
pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus/3.3/plexus-3.3.p
om (20 KB at 16.2 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.10/pl
exus-utils-3.0.10.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.10/ple
xus-utils-3.0.10.pom (4 KB at 7.0 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-io/2.0.6/plexus
-io-2.0.6.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-io/2.0.6/plexus-
io-2.0.6.pom (3 KB at 5.1 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-components/1.2/
plexus-components-1.2.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-components/1.2/p
lexus-components-1.2.pom (3 KB at 6.8 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.9/ple
xus-utils-3.0.9.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.9/plex
us-utils-3.0.9.pom (4 KB at 6.2 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/file-management/1.
2.1/file-management-1.2.1.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/file-management/1.2
.1/file-management-1.2.1.pom (4 KB at 6.4 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-io/1.
1/maven-shared-io-1.1.pom

Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-dependency-an
alyzer/1.4/maven-dependency-analyzer-1.4.jar (27 KB at 4.2 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-common-artif
act-filters/1.4/maven-common-artifact-filters-1.4.jar
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.9/plex
us-utils-3.0.9.jar (227 KB at 35.4 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-invoker/2.0.
11/maven-invoker-2.0.11.jar
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-dependency-tr
ee/2.1/maven-dependency-tree-2.1.jar (59 KB at 8.4 KB/sec)
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-common-artifa
ct-filters/1.4/maven-common-artifact-filters-1.4.jar (31 KB at 4.4 KB/sec)
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/asm/asm/3.3.1/asm-3.3.1.jar (43 KB at 5.9 K
B/sec)
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/eclipse/aether/aether-util/0.9.0.M2/aet
her-util-0.9.0.M2.jar (131 KB at 17.8 KB/sec)
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-invoker/2.0.1
1/maven-invoker-2.0.11.jar (29 KB at 3.8 KB/sec)
[INFO] com.yi.wechat:WechatDemo:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.mybatis:mybatis-spring:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:jstl:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:4.0.0-b07:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:3.0-alpha-1:compile
[INFO] +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:6.0.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- com.mchange:c3p0:jar:0.9.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.mchange:mchange-commons-java:jar:0.2.11:compile
[INFO] +- org.mybatis:mybatis:jar:3.4.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.shiro:shiro-all:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.shiro:shiro-lang:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.shiro:shiro-config-core:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.shiro:shiro-config-ogdl:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.shiro:shiro-crypto-core:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.shiro:shiro-crypto-hash:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.shiro:shiro-crypto-cipher:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.shiro:shiro-event:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.shiro:shiro-core:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.shiro:shiro-cache:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.shiro:shiro-web:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.shiro:shiro-aspectj:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.8.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.shiro:shiro-ehcache:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:jar:2.6.11:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.shiro:shiro-guice:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.inject:guice:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.google.inject.extensions:guice-multibindings:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.shiro:shiro-hazelcast:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.hazelcast:hazelcast:jar:3.7.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.shiro:shiro-quartz:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.opensymphony.quartz:quartz:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.shiro:shiro-spring:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO] +- net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- net.sf.ezmorph:ezmorph:jar:1.0.6:compile
[INFO] \- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.3.3:compile
[INFO]    \- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 02:17 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-07-10T22:00:57+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/29M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: what do you mean by opening tomcat? Starting a tomcat service ?

Comment: some sort of it.The log is Server Tomcat v8.5 Server at localhost failed to start.

Comment: It's unclear. If you have errors, please provide the logs.

Comment: All the situations have just the same exception.I've posted it.

Comment: There can be various reasons for this . Provide more logs

Comment: I've posted all the log.No missed  from the console.

Comment: Are you taking properties from outside like from properties file? Or are there any checks on the start of your application?

Comment: You have missed Apache Commons dependency

Comment: This is the project converted from dynamic project.It's fine before I change some mysql  code and java logic and add a common-upload.jar.Now it's wrong...pom.xml has no problem except the common-upload.jar.<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload -->
 <dependency>
     <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
     <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
     <version>1.3</version>
 </dependency>

Comment: What's wrong with pom.xml after you added the jar?

Comment: Now I know it's the problem with the apache commons-fileupload.jar .Tomcat was fine before I add it into my pom.xml file.

Comment: @doctorwhorm what problem did you got after adding the jar dependency?

Comment: Can't open the tomcat ,that's the problem I get.@npradeep357

Comment: Is it possible for you to paste the output of `mvn dependency:tree` command?

Comment: @Rishikesh,sorry,I am new to maven.Can't understanding what's the command it is.

Comment: @doctorwhorm just run the command on cmd

Comment: @doctorwhorm have you made maven build after adding dependency?

Comment: No.@npraddep357. I just save it,and it automatically download the jar in the Maven Dependency.No other operation.I've posted the command output above.

Comment: @doctorwhorm, please run it under your project directory on cmd.

Comment: @Rishikesh Darandal .Thank you all.I've solve it,I update the maven denpendencies by the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32090921/maven-invalid-loc-header-bad-signature  and it works! And I've post the new  cmd output above as you said.Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It is clearly saying that some of the following Class is not found :-

```
    org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileUploadException
```

You have to include this library into your project dependency library folder.

1. Get “commons-fileupload.jar” from official website – http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/
2. Get “commons-fileupload.jar” from Maven repository

   ```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
         <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
   ```

You need to put commons-fileupload.jar and commons-io.jar to your WEB-INF/lib forlder. Classpath is used during build, but they must be available during runtime also.

Actually, if you had used IDE for Java EE development (like Eclipse) putting these Jars to WEB-INF/lib would be enough, as they would be automatically visible in the claspath for build.

Comment: If he hadn't already added this dependency, how come he didn't got any compilation issues?

Comment: It can be the version Issues :)

Comment: Now I know it's class-not-found problem.But I've already add it in my pom.xml file.I try some other versions.

Comment: I concur with the version issue theory.

Comment: Please follow the Document  https://www.mkyong.com/struts/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-orgapachecommonsfileuploadfileuploadexception/

Comment: Awakawd......I haven't solve it.I don't know if it's the version problem.I am still figuring it.I've already change the version,still the same...

Comment: Okk
@doctorwhorm which version you are using ?
let me find the correct version of jar.

Comment: <version>1.3</version>

Comment: Thank you all.I've solve it,I update the maven denpendencies by the link 
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32090921/maven-invalid-loc-header-bad-signature     and it works.And sorry,@Hasnain Ali Bohra,my reputation is under 15,the system doesn't allow me to accept your answer...I tries it.