# Invalid LOC Header zipexception

Tags: java, testing

Actually I'm having an issue i can't explain. I'm getting the next exception in a  test which should go through al classes inside a concrete package and test one modeal function which everyone of them has to implement.

```
 @Test
  public void testConcreteModels()
      throws IOException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, NotFoundException, CannotCompileException {
    // Loop through classes in the model package
    final ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    for (final ClassPath.ClassInfo info : ClassPath.from(loader).getTopLevelClassesRecursive(MODEL_PACKAGE)) {
```

And the excepcion is next....

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(ZipFile.java:60)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:734)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(ZipFile.java:434)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
    at sun.misc.IOUtils.readFully(IOUtils.java:65)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getBytes(JarFile.java:425)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifestFromReference(JarFile.java:193)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifest(JarFile.java:180)
    at com.google.common.reflect.ClassPath$Scanner.scanJar(ClassPath.java:375)
    at com.google.common.reflect.ClassPath$Scanner.scanFrom(ClassPath.java:327)
    at com.google.common.reflect.ClassPath$Scanner.scan(ClassPath.java:315)
    at com.google.common.reflect.ClassPath.from(ClassPath.java:92)
    at com.sancorp.nwe.lcpccr.entity.EntityTest.testConcreteModels(EntityTest.java:40)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Any clue how to solve it???? I've already wipe my m2 repository in order to try to solve it but it didn't work :(

Comment: the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32090921/maven-invalid-loc-header-bad-signature doesn't help?

Comment: as I said I remove the whole .m2/repository several times, clean projects  and it didn't help.

Comment: I am talking about this https://stackoverflow.com/a/41914842/1746118

Comment: Maybe this here? https://github.com/google/guava/issues/1215

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after a few headaches I've discover the reason. Inside a component in the dependencies there were a package with same name.

Despite there were no matches in the classes' names it was trying to decompress a zip file there was no in the my project's claspath package... so it couses a io exception --> zipexception and so on.

I thought it should be another kind of exception, instead of  invalid LOC header (bad signature) but changing the package name it seems fixed.