# Server Tomcat v8.0 Server at localhost failed to start in eclipse

Tags: java, spring-mvc, pom.xml

I have a problem about starting Server tomcat v8.0. the error message - "Starting Tomcat v8.0 Server at localhost has encountered a problem. Server Tomcat v8.0 Server at localhost failed to start"
I have tried reinstalling eclipse and tomcat Server v8.0 and Spring. and when I created Spring MVC project and start to run on Sever, It worked. but when I import a project File progressing and start to run on Server,It didn't worked. and display the error message.
and I think the problem is in pom.xml of the imported project file because when I tried starting to run on server after transfering all codes of pom.xml of the imported project file to pom.xml of new project file, It didn't work. and display the same error message.

console log

```
12월 04, 2017 3:56:06 오후 org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
경고: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:controller' did not find a matching property.
12월 04, 2017 3:56:06 오후 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
정보: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.47
12월 04, 2017 3:56:06 오후 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
정보: Server built:          Sep 29 2017 13:46:41 UTC
12월 04, 2017 3:56:06 오후 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
정보: Server number:         8.0.47.0
12월 04, 2017 3:56:06 오후 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
정보: OS Name:               Windows 10
12월 04, 2017 3:56:06 오후 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
정보: OS Version:            10.0
12월 04, 2017 3:56:06 오후 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
정보: Architecture:          amd64
12월 04, 2017 3:56:06 오후 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
정보: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre
12월 04, 2017 3:56:06 오후 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
정보: JVM Version:           1.8.0_144-b01
12월 04, 2017 3:56:06 오후 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
정보: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
12월 04, 2017 3:56:06 오후 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
정보: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\Song JiEun\workspace3\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
12월 04, 2017 3:56:06 오후 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
정보: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0
12월 04, 2017 3:56:06 오후 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
정보: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\Song JiEun\workspace3\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
12월 04, 2017 3:56:06 오후 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
정보: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0
12월 04, 2017 3:56:06 오후 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
정보: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\Song JiEun\workspace3\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
12월 04, 2017 3:56:06 오후 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
정보: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\endorsed
12월 04, 2017 3:56:06 오후 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
정보: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=MS949
12월 04, 2017 3:56:06 오후 org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
정보: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_144/bin/../jre/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_144/bin/../jre/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_144/bin/../jre/lib/amd64;%CDSROOT%\OpenAccess\bin\win32\opt;%CDSROOT%\tools\pcb\bin;%CDSROOT%\tools\fet\bin;%CDSROOT%\tools\Capture;%CDSROOT%\tools\PSpice;%CDSROOT%\tools\specctra\bin;%CDSROOT%\tools\bin;%CDSROOT%\tools\PSpice\Library;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Utilities 1.6\;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Production Server\R2015a\runtime\win64;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Production Server\R2015a\bin;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Production Server\R2015a\polyspace\bin;C:\Cadence\SPB_17.2\OpenAccess\bin\win32\opt;C:\Cadence\SPB_17.2\tools\pcb\bin;C:\Cadence\SPB_17.2\tools\fet\bin;C:\Cadence\SPB_17.2\tools\Capture;C:\Cadence\SPB_17.2\tools\PSpice;C:\Cadence\SPB_17.2\tools\specctra\bin;C:\Cadence\SPB_17.2\tools\bin;C:\Cadence\SPB_17.2\tools\PSpice\Library;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Users\Song JiEun\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Users\Song JiEun\Desktop\eclipse-jee-mars-2-win32-x86_64\eclipse;;.
12월 04, 2017 3:56:06 오후 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
정보: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
12월 04, 2017 3:56:07 오후 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
정보: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
12월 04, 2017 3:56:07 오후 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
정보: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
12월 04, 2017 3:56:07 오후 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
정보: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
12월 04, 2017 3:56:07 오후 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
정보: Initialization processed in 1592 ms
12월 04, 2017 3:56:07 오후 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
정보: Starting service Catalina
12월 04, 2017 3:56:07 오후 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
정보: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.47
12월 04, 2017 3:56:07 오후 org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
심각: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/controller]]
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:943)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/controller]]
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
 ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@478a19e2]
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4969)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5102)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
 ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@671aee2]
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:135)
 at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:722)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
 ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
 at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:113)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
 ... 12 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
 at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
 at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(ZipFile.java:60)
 at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:734)
 at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(ZipFile.java:434)
 at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
 at sun.misc.IOUtils.readFully(IOUtils.java:65)
 at java.util.jar.JarFile.getBytes(JarFile.java:425)
 at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifestFromReference(JarFile.java:193)
 at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifest(JarFile.java:180)
 at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:111)
 ... 13 more
12월 04, 2017 3:56:07 오후 org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
심각: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:943)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:441)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:789)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:630)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:951)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
 ... 6 more
12월 04, 2017 3:56:07 오후 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
심각: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:630)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:789)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
 ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:441)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
 ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:951)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
 ... 11 more
12월 04, 2017 3:56:07 오후 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
정보: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
12월 04, 2017 3:56:07 오후 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
정보: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
12월 04, 2017 3:56:07 오후 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
정보: Stopping service Catalina
12월 04, 2017 3:56:07 오후 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
정보: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
12월 04, 2017 3:56:07 오후 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
심각: Failed to destroy end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.releaseCaches(NioEndpoint.java:315)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.unbind(NioEndpoint.java:491)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.destroy(AbstractEndpoint.java:896)
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy(AbstractProtocol.java:551)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.destroyInternal(Connector.java:1023)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:589)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:879)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:634)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
12월 04, 2017 3:56:07 오후 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
정보: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
12월 04, 2017 3:56:07 오후 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
심각: Failed to destroy end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.releaseCaches(NioEndpoint.java:315)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.unbind(NioEndpoint.java:491)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.destroy(AbstractEndpoint.java:896)
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy(AbstractProtocol.java:551)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.destroyInternal(Connector.java:1023)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:589)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:879)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:634)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
```

and pom.xml of imported project file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.zerock</groupId>
    <artifactId>controller</artifactId>
    <name>wIThMovie</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <java-version>1.8</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>4.2.3.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
    </properties> 

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>oracle</id>
            <name>ORACLE JDBC Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.jahia.org/maven2</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>sonatype-oss-snapshots</id>
            <name>Sonatype OSS Snapshots Repository</name>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories> 

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bgee.log4jdbc-log4j2</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4jdbc-log4j2-jdbc4</artifactId>
            <version>1.16</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- @Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.21</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-dbcp/commons-dbcp -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- MultipartHttpServletRequset -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I think the problem is in pom.xml.

Comment: this might be related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32090921/maven-invalid-loc-header-bad-signature

Comment: Thank you~!! I I think the problem can be resolved from your help