# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlObject

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, apache-poi, xmlbeans

I am getting the following error,

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlObject
```

I'm using Maven and have included the poi and poi-ooxml dependencies. This installed the xmlBeans jar so i'm not sure why it isn't working.

[image: These are the jars I currently have installed]

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Could you please check the contents of the jar and ensure the class exists? It's possible the type got moved to a different package or was removed.

Comment: The class does exist but when I try open it i get the error 'invalid LOC header (bad signature)'

Comment: Sounds like the jar is corrupted. This question's second answer may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32090921/deploying-maven-project-throws-java-util-zip-zipexception-invalid-loc-header-b

Comment: That worked! Thank you :)

Comment: No problem, I'll go ahead and write an answer. Could you please up vote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the jar is corrupt. Try the second answer from the following question: [Deploying Maven project throws java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32090921/deploying-maven-project-throws-java-util-zip-zipexception-invalid-loc-header-b)

In other words:

1. Try removing the contents of the local repository directory. On Windows this is located at:  C:\Users[username].m2\repository folder.
2. In Eclipse, right-click on the project and select Maven->Update Project. Ensure the Force Update of Snapshots/Releases is selected.