# Vaadin Context Menu Add On Error for 3.0.0.beta, but works for 2.1.0

Tags: vaadin, contextmenu, vaadin8, vaadin-grid

I am using Vaadin 8 and want to add-on latest 3.0.0.beta1 vaadin-context-menu.
The maven update and build works fine but Tomcat fails to start with

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
   <artifactId>vaadin-context-menu</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.0.beta1</version>
</dependency>
```

I am getting Error with Message "java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)"

However, I able to successfully implement Context Menu for version 2.1.0

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-context-menu</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that the JAR is broken. There is a bug in Eclipse's  maven that breaks JARs randomly. Just delete it from .m2 cache and let maven redownload it.

The bug is described here https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=534228

There is another StackOverflow discussion about the corrupt JAR's here, with solution how to find them: [Deploying Maven project throws java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32090921/deploying-maven-project-throws-java-util-zip-zipexception-invalid-loc-header-b)

```
find  /home/me/.m2/repository/ -name "*jar" | xargs -L 1 zip -T | grep error | grep invalid
```

Comment: Clearing the cache didnt work either, the compile widgetset fails.

Comment: @SDS Did you clear it from the invisible Maven cache or just the Eclipse cache?