# Java Maven project build failure

Tags: java, maven, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have created a Java project to push data to an Apache Kafka server (this project is error free, according to my IDE).
When I try to run `Maven -> Install`, my build fails.

I receive the following error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5:single (default) on project kafka_producer: Failed to create assembly: Error creating assembly archive jar-with-dependencies: Problem creating jar: invalid LOC header (bad signature) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

If I am going to delete data from the `m2.` folder and try to update project, its taking more time(for 2 hours only 2% update). and also it affects all other project in workspace.

Let me know how to resolve the issue in eclipse.
Below is the pom.xml:

---

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>kafka</groupId>
  <artifactId>Kafka_Producer</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  
 <properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  </properties> 
  
<profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>windows_profile</id>
      <activation>
        <os>
          <family>Windows</family>
        </os>
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <toolsjar>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</toolsjar>
      </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>osx_profile</id>
      <activation>
        <os>
          <family>mac</family>
        </os>
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <toolsjar>${java.home}/../Classes/classes.jar</toolsjar>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>   

  
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.11</version>
        </dependency>   
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-hdfs -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
           <!-- <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions> -->
        </dependency>           
        
        <dependency>
           <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
           <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
           <version>3.2.0</version>
            <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
           </exclusions> 
        </dependency>       
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.relevantcodes/extentreports -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>2.41.2</version>
        </dependency>    
    
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-compiler-plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
        <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>   
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hive/hive-exec -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
        <artifactId>hive-exec</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    

    
    <!--  From Hive project -->
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  
    <!--  <dependency>
        <groupId>jdk.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdk.tools</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.0_05</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${JAVA_HOME}/lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency> 
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jdk.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdk.tools</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${JAVA_HOME}/lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency> -->


    <dependency>
<groupId>jdk.tools</groupId>
<artifactId>jdk.tools</artifactId>
<version>1.8.0_171</version>
<scope>system</scope>
<systemPath>${JAVA_HOME}/lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hive/hive-hbase-handler -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
        <artifactId>hive-hbase-handler</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-common -->
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-core -->
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-client -->

    
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.fge/json-schema-validator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.fge</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.fge/jackson-coreutils -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.fge</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-coreutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.fge/json-schema-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.fge</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-schema-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>   
        
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.javacsv/javacsv -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.javacsv</groupId>
        <artifactId>javacsv</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    
        
    

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.11</version>
        </dependency>   
        
<!--Dependencies-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-junit</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.relevantcodes/extentreports -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>2.41.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mongodb-driver</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>        
       
        
    
        
  </dependencies>     
  <build>
   <resources>
    <resource>
       <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    </resource>
   </resources>  
   <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
              </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
            <mainClass>SparkCassandra.GetPacketsTime</mainClass>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
         <descriptorRefs>
           <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
         </descriptorRefs>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>  
  <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>assemble-all</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <!--<finalName>PROJECT_NAME-${project.version}-shaded</finalName>-->
                        <relocations>
                            <relocation>
                                <pattern>com.google.common</pattern>
                                <shadedPattern>shaded.com.google.common</shadedPattern>
                            </relocation>
                            <relocation>
                                <pattern>com.google.protobuf</pattern>
                                <shadedPattern>shaded.com.google.protobuf</shadedPattern>
                            </relocation>
                        </relocations>
                        <artifactSet>
                            <includes>
                                <include>*:*</include>
                            </includes>
                        </artifactSet>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>     
  </plugins>
 </build>     
  
  
</project>
```

---

Comment: Did you try using the - e or -X switch as the error message suggested? And did you follow the link given by it?

Comment: Can you post your pom file, or at least the <build> portion?

Comment: updated pom.xml file. please let me now how to solve this in eclipse.

Comment: First try on plain command line not from within Eclipse furthermore delete your local cache and active checksum policy in you settings.xml and rebuild..There had been download/network/proxy/virus scan issue with those artifacts... (Details https://blog.soebes.de/blog/2018/10/13/maven-artifact-checksums-what/)

Answer (score 2):

Try to run maven with `mvn clean install -U`.

It will force a re-download of all the JARs, so if one is corrupted it will get a new copy.  It sounds similar to corruption issues noted here: [Deploying Maven project throws java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32090921/deploying-maven-project-throws-java-util-zip-zipexception-invalid-loc-header-b).

They recommend other solutions; but I think `-U` **may** suffice.

Comment: I am using Windows machine and running project in scala ide with Java perspective, once right click on project -run as -maven clean and install ,I am doing .But how to specify this options .

Comment: I'm not an eclipse user; but usually its features match IntelliJ pretty well.   IntelliJ has a button that you can click to manually specify a maven command, so eclipse probably does too.  If not, it probably has a command line you can open up to type the command.  In any case, its generally a good idea to have a way to run commands manually; most developers I know have maven installed outside their IDE so they can do stuff like this from the normal windows/linux command line.  That's a good idea :).

Answer (score 1):

This error usually indicates a corrupted jar in your repository.

One way to fix is the issue is to remove just the relevant jars from your maven repo (usually /home/[user]/.m2/repository/) , and re-try.

Comment: How to know which jars are corrupted ? I am using Windows machine and running project in scala ide with Java perspective.

Comment: Try running with -X switch (and possibly -e), and hopefully you'll get more information about which jars are corrupted.