# Unable to run basic jhipster project

Tags: jhipster

I'm trying to create a jhipster project to follow this tutorial
https://rphgoossens.wordpress.com/2018/03/28/getting-the-jhipsters-aboard/

and with the next options:

```
? Which *type* of application would you like to create? Monolithic application (recommended for simple projects)
? What is the base name of your application? brewery
? What is your default Java package name? com.example.org
? Do you want to use the JHipster Registry to configure, monitor and scale your application? No
? Which *type* of authentication would you like to use? JWT authentication (stateless, with a token)
? Which *type* of database would you like to use? SQL (H2, MySQL, MariaDB, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MSSQL)
? Which *production* database would you like to use? MySQL
? Which *development* database would you like to use? H2 with in-memory persistence
? Do you want to use the Spring cache abstraction? Yes, with the Ehcache implementation (local cache, for a single node)

? Do you want to use Hibernate 2nd level cache? Yes
? Would you like to use Maven or Gradle for building the backend? Maven
? Which other technologies would you like to use? Search engine using Elasticsearch
? Which *Framework* would you like to use for the client? Angular
? Would you like to enable *SASS* stylesheet preprocessor? No
? Would you like to enable internationalization support? Yes
? Please choose the native language of the application Spanish
? Please choose additional languages to install English
? Besides JUnit and Jest, which testing frameworks would you like to use? Gatling
? Would you like to install other generators from the JHipster Marketplace? No
```

Once the project is created I run backend using mvnw (Windows) and at the end of the process I get next error:

```
The Class-Path manifest attribute in C:\Users\david\.m2\repository\org\liquibase\liquibase-core\3.5.5\liquibase-core-3.5.5.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: 

file:/C:/Users/david/.m2/repository/org/liquibase/liquibase-core/3.5.5/lib/snakeyaml-1.13.jar
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to read Class-Path attribute from manifest of jar file:/C:/Users/david/.m2/repository/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.5/gson-2.8.5.jar


       at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls.getUrlsFromClassPathOfJarManifestIfPossible(ChangeableUrls.java:132)
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls.fromClassLoader(ChangeableUrls.java:98)
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.DefaultRestartInitializer.getUrls(DefaultRestartInitializer.java:91)
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.DefaultRestartInitializer.getInitialUrls(DefaultRestartInitializer.java:55)
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter.<init>(Restarter.java:142)
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter.initialize(Restarter.java:556)
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartApplicationListener.onApplicationStartingEvent(RestartApplicationListener.java:67)
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(RestartApplicationListener.java:45)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.starting(EventPublishingRunListener.java:68)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.starting(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:48)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:293)
        at com.example.org.BreweryApp.main(BreweryApp.java:63)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(ZipFile.java:60)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:717)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(ZipFile.java:419)
        at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
        at sun.misc.IOUtils.readFully(IOUtils.java:65)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.getBytes(JarFile.java:425)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifestFromReference(JarFile.java:193)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifest(JarFile.java:180)
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls.getUrlsFromManifestClassPathAttribute(ChangeableUrls.java:153)
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls.getUrlsFromClassPathOfJarManifestIfPossible(ChangeableUrls.java:129)
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47320971/3737815