# org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component -org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet

Tags: spring, eclipse, web-applications, tomcat9

In my web application using Java 8, tomcat 9 and Eclipse IDE and I faced this problem while starting tomcat. Is there any suggestion to solve  this problem? Thanks.

```
07-Jul-2023 15:46:31.437 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal A child container failed during start
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@30ec211a]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:923)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1383)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:265)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:430)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:347)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:478)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@30ec211a]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:173)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:752)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4881)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5014)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1383)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
        ... 21 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:143)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
        ... 33 more
    Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(ZipFile.java:60)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:717)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(ZipFile.java:419)
        at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
        at sun.misc.IOUtils.readFully(IOUtils.java:65)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.getBytes(JarFile.java:425)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifestFromReference(JarFile.java:193)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifest(JarFile.java:180)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:141)
```

I deleted tomcat configuration and reinstall server, I deleted maven lib folders but doesn't work

Comment: Hello! Look's like you're having the similar issue from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32090921/deploying-maven-project-throws-java-util-zip-zipexception-invalid-loc-header-b) question. Did you watched it?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Invalid LOC header - a sign of a broken jar file.

Maybe you should delete the .m2\repository directory.

**But first make the necessary backups**

Comment: Failing that, perhaps a fresh Tomcat download is also a good idea.